# How can I run a ruby file in command line from Java?

Tags: java, command-line, command-prompt, runtime.exec

I want to run a Ruby file in a given path, from Java.

For instance: **C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\myruby.rb**

In the command line i need to run the ruby file `ruby myruby.rb`

I have tried the following code but it's not working:

```
final String[] command = new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\ruby myruby.rb"};

final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

My **myruby.rb** file contains the following code:

```
puts "Hello"
```

The above builds sucessfully. But **"Hello"** is not printed.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting the file name in quotes?

```
final String[] command = new String[]{"cmd", "/c",
       "\"C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\ruby muruby.rb\""};
```

Comment: Yes i run successfully. But I have puts "Hello" in myruby.rb. Which is not print.